# What do we call lips squeezing back?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

To my mind, **to pout** means *to push one's lips forward*, as an expression of petulant annoyance or sexual attraction. **To pucker one's lips** has a similar meaning.

I am wondering what the opposite expression is called, namely pulling one's lips back. I am not sure **scrunch** would do, as it signifies the crumbling and squeezing of face.

Here's an image example of such a facial expression from a movie.

[image]

Comment: A slight problem is you have with your example is there are two expressions going on at the same time: the girl is both ***pursing*** her lips and ***smirking*** *(to her right)*.

Answer (score 6):

My first thought is "pursing" lips, e.g. "She pursed her lips when she heard me fart."

Pursed comes from an old-fashioned money purse that closes by a drawstring. It wrinkles the top of the purse, so [pursed means "wrinkled"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pursed) as in the picture you show.

Comment: Edit to add a dictionary link

Answer (score 3):

> She screwed up her lips.
>
> She screwed up her mouth.
>
> Her lips drew back (in a smirk/disbelief).

All of these work in your described context. **To screw up one's lips** especially can depict a facial expression where the lips are pulled and twisted to one side of the face. Think of a scene where a person twists their lips aside to exhale smoke in order to not puff in their conversation partner's face. There are examples in novels of this common scene:

> “Can I sit in front?” Lux asked, **screwing her mouth up** to exhale to one side, politely away from us. (Source: [The Virgin Suicides by Jeffrey Eugenides](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pf1xhp6u-w0C&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=screwing%20up%20her%20mouth%20to%20exhale%20to%20one%20side,%20politely%20away%20from%20us&source=bl&ots=Ne9G_od4od&sig=gH23iiHVb3h3hEP7yxkZIb4Edls&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYxeuk6LLaAhWowFQKHYEsClkQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=screwing%20up%20her%20mouth%20to%20exhale%20to%20one%20side%2C%20politely%20away%20from%20us&f=false))

If I am not mistaken, the screenshot is from the movie *Tracks*. Incidentally, I found an audio-described copy of the film and it actually uses **screw up one's lips** in this scene. As far as the actual scene from the movie is concerned, I don't think it's a smirk or skepticism that she is displaying (as another answer suggests).

> Sallay to Robyn: If you're out there on your own and a wild bull's coming at ya, you shoot it. Don't think. You shoot. You understand?
>
> (She **screws up her lips**.)

You can also say *screw up one's face* or *screw up one's eyes*.

Answer (score 2):

I'd describe the woman in the photo as having an expression of **skepticism** or **disbelief**. In that light, I'd suggest one of the following phrases:

> A **skeptical smirk** came across her face.
>
> The **corner of her mouth quirked up** into a disbelieving smirk.
>
> She gave a **skeptical half-smile**.
>
> She shot him a **disbelieving look**.

I found the following link useful as a reference for describing facial expressions:

[MASTER LIST of Facial Expressions for Writers!](http://www.bryndonovan.com/2015/04/05/master-list-of-facial-expressions/)

Comment: +1 Great answer! I will wait a bit longer to see if other ideas emerge before I settle on your answer.