# What is this action called: a kid protrudes his lips and makes a sound like a mouse?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> **[squeak](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/squeak_1?q=squeak)** /skwiːk/ [intransitive] to make a short high sound that is not very loud
>
> My new shoes squeak.
>
> The mouse ran away, squeaking with fear.
>
> One wheel makes a horrible squeaking noise.

My kid often protrudes his lips and makes a sound like a mouse as in [this video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WKkWWn-L5tXewA0q-VoQsoYthjT5N_9a).

**What is this action called: a kid protrudes his lips and makes a sound like a mouse?**

I am not sure if we can say "**he is squeaking**"

Comment: also related: [What do we call lips squeezing back?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162773/what-do-we-call-lips-squeezing-back)

Comment: Related: [What are these called: to purse your lips?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235617/what-are-these-called-to-purse-your-lips)

Comment: @Mari-LouA But neither of those mentions making a sound. I don't really know what you would call that sound - I suppose **squeak** is the nearest.